# emphasis in the theorem enviroment

Tags: theorems, emphasis

I'm doing a project in soluble gorups and I begin by defining a subnormal series. In this definition the words "factors" and "length" are both emphasised. However, in the theorem enviroment, the \emph{} command simply un-italicizes the words. This change is too subtle and I feel like I only noticed the difference because I knew it was there. Is there a beter way of going about this?

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{def}{Definition}

\begin{document}
 \begin{def}
  A subnormal series for a group $G$ is a chain of normal subgroups 
  \[\{1\}=A_0\triangleleft A_1\triangleleft\cdots\triangleleft A_n=G.\]
  The quotient groups $A_{i+1}/A_i$ are called the \emph{factors} of the
  series and the number of strict inclusions is called the \emph{length} 
  of the series.
 \end{def}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What would you like the "inner" emphasis to look like? Bolding? Small-caps? Something else? Please advise.

Comment: Just change it by redefining `\eminnershape`, I often use italic bold in that case.

Comment: I'm not really too sure. I think bold italics would look best but ideally I would like to avoid textbf{}.

Comment: I've never used \eminnershape before is it possible to get an example?

Comment: this may be irrelevant to your situation, but if (since you are using `amsart`) are intending to submit something to the ams for publication, be warned that bold for emphasis is strongly discouraged, and your use of it may be changed.

Comment: Could you suggest a more suitable alternative?

Answer (score 4):

- If you want the "inner" emphasis mode to be ***italic bold***, run following instruction in the preamble:

  ```
  \renewcommand\eminnershape{\bfseries}
  ```

  (In all cases, I will assume that the "outer" emphasis mode is *non-bold italic*.)
- If you want the "inner" emphasis mode to be **non-italic bold**, run following instruction in the preamble:

  ```
  \renewcommand\eminnershape{\upshape\bfseries}
  ```
- If you want the "inner" emphasis mode to be non-italic small caps, run following instruction in the preamble:

  ```
  \renewcommand\eminnershape{\upshape\scshape}
  ```